# Database design: Managing old and new data in database table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql, database-design

I have a table `Student` with field as followed,

**Student** table (one record per student)

```
student_id
Name 
Parent_Name
Address_line1, Address_line2, Addess_line
Photo_path
Signature_file_path
Preferred_examcity_choice1,Preferred_examcity_choice1, Preferred_examcity_choice3
Gender
Nationality
.
.
.
```

I am inserting into this table on Registration form completion through the web interface.

Now there is one more module in a web interface for updating the student data, on every update request I am updating the `student` table records and inserting the new entry in `student_data_change_request`. student can change records any number of times.

**student_data_change_request**

```
request_id(auto_incr PK)
old_name
new_name
old_photo_path
new_photo_path
old_signature_file_path
new_signature_file_path
```

Now coming to problem, earlier students were allowed to change very few fields, now client want to allow the candidate to update more number of fields(around 20 fields) and adding `old` and `new` columns for the corresponding column isn't elegant and preferred(I guess), I will end up creating 40 columns to keep track of 20 columns. So how should I redesign my table? suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to have a shadow table named (table)_xx that has the same columns, the time, date, update/insert/delete flag, user or whatever and no referential integrity. Set a trigger to update that table from the source whenever anything happens.

If you've got genuine business requirements that need history then do those properly but this pattern is great as a general audit, debugging and forensic tool.

It's also really easy to automate/script as you just generate it from the DB metadata.

Comment: +1 For this solution. Also with Oracle 12c the Flashback Technology helps you achieve this much easier. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01001

Comment: Yes Oracle Flashback is great though not universally supported.  SQL Server has a few options now but as far as I can tell not quite this.

Answer (score 0):

Usually historical table looks like:

```
request_id
column_name
old_value
new_value
dt
```

**request_id** and **column_name** are primary key. When you update **student** table you insert new entry in **student_data_change_request** for each updating column.

**Edited**:
Another way:

```
request_id
value_type
name
photo_path
signature_file_path
...
```

and insert first entry with old values and second entry with new values. Colum **value_type** is mark **old** or **new**.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather have just one table, with an additional column for effective date. Then a view that picks up just the most recent row for each student_id becomes your first "table". If for some reason you must show "current" and "most recently changed" values side-by-side, that is another view.

Comment: actually, student ID is a primary key,  I can not have two records for one Student.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it all depends on how you intend to use the data.

My strong preference in these cases is the solution @mathguy suggests - embedding the concept of time in the main table design. This allows you to ask the question "what was this student's address on 1 Jan?", or "who had signature x on 12 Feb?".

If you have to report or execute business logic that reflects the status at any point in time, this design works really well. For instance, if you have to report on how many students lived in a particular address for a given term, you want to know when the records were valid.

But not all applications care about "time" - sometimes, you just want to have an audit table, so you can trace what happened over time in case of anomalies.

In that case, @loztinspace's solution is useful - but in my experience, this rapidly escalates into more work, because those who want to inspect the audit records can or should not get access to a SQL prompt on your production environment.